# How to run sql query stored in a variable with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to run a sql query that I store in a variable in Laravel. It's really easy to do in CodeIgniter with just running `$this->db->sql($sql)`. I wonder if there is a way like this in Laravel.

```
  $sql = "SELECT u.*,c.city_name,prov.province_name FROM users u ".
        "LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.city_id=u.city_id".
        "LEFT JOIN provinces prov ON prov.province_id=u.province_id".
        "WHERE u.id= ?";
```

I tried to execute it using `DB::table($sql)` but I guess that's not the way.

EDIT:
Using the following is working fine but I still wonder if I just can run something like I do in CI with running `$this->db->query($sql)`.

```
$user = User::select('users.*','cities.city_name','provinces.province_name')
           ->where('users.id', Auth::id())
           ->leftJoin('cities','cities.city_id','=','users.city_id')
           ->leftJoin('provinces','provinces.province_id','=','users.province_id')
           ->get()->first();
```

Comment: As @Martin Adiputra said you need to use DB::select and pass parameters as shown in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);
```

refer the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries

so if you

```
$sql = "SELECT u.*,c.city_name,prov.province_name FROM users u ".
        "LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.city_id=u.city_id".
        "LEFT JOIN provinces prov ON prov.province_id=u.province_id".
        "WHERE u.id= ?";
```

just try

```
$query_result = DB::select($sql, [your parameter variable]);
```

Comment: yes, i have no problem with this. but I'm looking to possibility of other way which I think is easier for me

Answer (score 0):

Create eloquent relationships in models. When there is a relationship between models, you do not have to create a long sql query. You can refer to their documentation. It is really easy to understand. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: definitely will learn about this but I have no time at the moment so I'm still looking to other solution closer to what I expect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rows = DB::select(
    DB::raw($sql, array($stringids))
);
```